# How to use session storage data in multi layer architecture in C# with ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session, multi-layer

I am working on a project and using N-Layer architecture (web layer, service layer, data access layer).

I am facing an issue regarding the use of session storage in the data access layer.

I am storing data in the web layer (controller) and I want to use the session stored data in data access layer. Is this possible? If yes then please let me know...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add some example code to demonstrate your issue.

Answer (score 2):

Shortly: this is possible.

Easy (and really bad) way is to reference web libraries in your data layer and use `HttpContext.Current.Session`. This will break all the flexibility you got before with your code structure when separating layers.

A bit longer (but much nicer way) is to install some IOC container. It will allow to declare some interfaces in data layer, and register session providers in the presentation layer.

I am going to show the workflow with Ninject. For example, you have some service (`SomeService`) in the data layer, that needs to operate on data from session. We can use abstractions since `SomeService` does not really care about origin of the data, it is not that important.

```
namespace DataLayer
{
    public interface ISomeDataProvider
    {
        string GetData();
    }
}

namespace DataLayer
{
    public class SomeService
    {
        private readonly ISomeDataProvider someDataProvider;

        public SomeService(ISomeDataProvider someDataProvider)
        {
            this.someDataProvider = someDataProvider;
        }

        public void DoThing()
        {
            var data = someDataProvider.GetData();
        }
    }
}
```

Lets move on to presentation layer. Now we should create implementation for our interface from data layer.

```
using DataLayer;
using System.Web;

namespace WebProject.App_Start
{
    internal class SessionDataProvider : ISomeDataProvider
    {
        public string GetData()
        {
            return HttpContext.Current.Session["data"].ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, we need to configure dependency injection to use our implementation, whenever `ISomeDataProvider` is used in the constructor. There are plenty of articles about installing Ninject on the web, I recommend `Ninject.MVC3` package. Once you install it, you will have `NinjectWebCommon.cs` look something similar to this.

```
[assembly: WebActivatorEx.PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(WebProject.App_Start.NinjectWebCommon), "Start")]
[assembly: WebActivatorEx.ApplicationShutdownMethodAttribute(typeof(WebProject.App_Start.NinjectWebCommon), "Stop")]

namespace WebProject.App_Start
{
    using System;
    using System.Web;
    using DataLayer;
    using Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.DynamicModuleHelper;

    using Ninject;
    using Ninject.Web.Common;

    public static class NinjectWebCommon 
    {
        private static readonly Bootstrapper bootstrapper = new Bootstrapper();

        /// <summary>
        /// Starts the application
        /// </summary>
        public static void Start() 
        {
            DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(OnePerRequestHttpModule));
            DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(NinjectHttpModule));
            bootstrapper.Initialize(CreateKernel);
        }
        
        /// <summary>
        /// Stops the application.
        /// </summary>
        public static void Stop()
        {
            bootstrapper.ShutDown();
        }
        
        /// <summary>
        /// Creates the kernel that will manage your application.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>The created kernel.</returns>
        private static IKernel CreateKernel()
        {
            var kernel = new StandardKernel();
            try
            {
                kernel.Bind<Func<IKernel>>().ToMethod(ctx => () => new Bootstrapper().Kernel);
                kernel.Bind<IHttpModule>().To<HttpApplicationInitializationHttpModule>();

                RegisterServices(kernel);
                return kernel;
            }
            catch
            {
                kernel.Dispose();
                throw;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Load your modules or register your services here!
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="kernel">The kernel.</param>
        private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
        {
            kernel.Bind<ISomeDataProvider>().To<SessionDataProvider>().InRequestScope();
        }        
    }
}
```

What is the most important here is this line `kernel.Bind<ISomeDataProvider>().To<SessionDataProvider>().InRequestScope();`. It will configure `SomeService` to use `SessionDataProvider` in data layer without actually referencing all the web dlls in the data layer and bypassing circular dependency

Finally, inject your service in the controller`s constructor

```
using DataLayer;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace WebProject.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly SomeService someService;

        public HomeController(SomeService someService)
        {
            this.someService = someService;
        }

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            someService.DoThing();
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you want to do here is implement a custom SessionStateStoreProvider.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.sessionstate.sessionstatestoreproviderbase?view=netframework-4.8

Then Session can be implemented as a data layer abstraction and easily shared in that layer.